# Error accured in reading files by using line by line in c

Tags: c

log.txt :

```
Hello world 
world is not enough 
to show our knowledge
```

cpp file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char szLine[512+1]={0};
   FILE *fp=fopen("log.txt", "r");
   while(!feof(fp))
   {
      fscanf(fp, "%512[^\n]", szLine);
      puts(szLine);
      getchar();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Acually expected output for this program has to read line by line. But it read only first line alone. What is the mistake on this code. thanks advance.

Comment: Isn't there only one line in Your `log.txt`?

Comment: actually i added 3 lines but it shows this as single line. sorry. Now tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Because it is not processing newline remaining.

Comment: The use of feof like this is not good. In order to read too much. timing to become eof because deviates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char szLine[512+1]={0};
   FILE *fp=fopen("log.txt", "r");
   while(!feof(fp))
   {
      fgets(szLine,512,fp);
      puts(szLine);
      getchar();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
while(fscanf(fp, " %512[^\n]", szLine)==1)
{
   puts(szLine);
   getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks the empty space alone make the diff between the " and %. Now its working fyn.

Answer (score 1):

because the offset of the file stream always be 0, so you read

Answer (score 1):

"%512[^\n]" does not read the endline character. The remaining part of the file starts with \n and fscanf fails to read the line(it return 0 instead of 1). You need to read the endline character !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int bla;
    char szLine[512+1]={0};
    FILE *fp=fopen("log.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        bla= fscanf(fp, "%512[^\n]", szLine);
        if(bla==1){
            printf("%d\n",bla);
            puts(szLine);
            getchar();
            fgetc(fp);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using getline() may be a more reliable solution.

```
 getline(&szLine,&size,fp);
```

Bye,

Francis